# How do I debug an Actionscript project in Flex builder?

Tags: debugging, flexbuilder, actionscript

I am trying to use Flex builder for the first time in years. I haven't used the "Run Application" option before, and when I do that now it tells me "Errors exist in required projects" and whether I should proceed. I would like to debug those errors.

Does anyone know how I can do that?

PS: When I click the "Debug" button, it does exactly the same thing. I don't see error output in the console views.

Comment: Isn't this a Stack Overflow question?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is probably related to compilation (source) errors.
You need to correct them before you can debug or run.
If you ask to proceed, the project is executed as it was after the last good compilation.
If there was never a good compilation, then nothing will execute.

Comment: How can I correct the compilation errors? Where can I see them? Flex only gives me a pop up to say there are errors, but won't tell me how to find them :-(

Comment: Another related question: can I check for compilation errors in included libraries without opening and inspecting every file?

Comment: I remember vaguely that there was an Errors pane.

Answer (score 0):

here is a detailed description about debugging

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/1/flex_builder_en/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Using_Flex_Builder&file=brady318.htm

**Errors exist in required projects**

To solve this problem try re-installing your Flex builder in your Windows installed Drive Eg. C:\ (not sure if it will work)

In Windows Menu Menu > Problems , you can get a summary of all problems in all project files